# In Scala, process a list of items with a Try operation, and keep the original item to report the possible failure

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a list of strings, and I want to make several transformation to each item. I want to keep the original string, so that I can show it if it was invalid. Example as follows:

```
import scala.util.Try

val list = List("<entry id='1'/>", "haha", "<entry id='hehe'/>")

def parseXML(str: String) = Try { xml.XML.loadString(str) }

list
  .map(parseXML)
  .map(tryEntry => tryEntry.map(entry => (entry \ "@id").text))
  .map(tryId => tryId.flatMap(id => Try(id.toInt)))

// here I lose the original string
res17: List[Try[Int]] = List(
  Success(1),
  Failure(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.),
  Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hehe")
)

// here I keep a copy of the original string, so I can report the invalid entry to the user
list
  .map(l => (l, parseXML(l)))
  .map { case(line, tryEntry) => (line, tryEntry.map(entry => (entry \ "@id").text)) }
  .map { case(line, tryId) => (line, tryId.flatMap(id => Try(id.toInt))) }

res19: List[(String, Try[Int])] = List(
  ("<entry id='1'/>", Success(1)),
  ("haha", Failure(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.)),
  ("<entry id='hehe'/>", Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "hehe"))
)
```

In res19, I keep a copy of the original string, so I can report the error and the original string. However, I need to carry this information each time during a mapping operation, and this is ugly. Is there a better way? (maybe using ScalaZ `State` and `for`?)

Comment: In the second comment, I think "so I cannot report" should be "so I can report"

Comment: thx @pascal-soucy, fixed.

Comment: I would probably just define an error case class that captures both the underlying exception and the original string. You map that over the failure side in `parseXML` and then work with your tries as usual.

Comment: yes, but I would need to do that in `parseXML`, in `id.toInt`, and many other places. that is ugly.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Well, you could use `Writer` (or more or less equivalently the monad for `Tuple2[String, ?]`), which lets you chain your maps as desired, but `list.traverse(...)`, etc. won't have the right semantics—you'll have to cash out each writer operation before sequencing.

Comment: `Writer` is what I once looked at and I thought it could be useful here, but I couldn't remember. Thx! However, I see that it results in `Writer[List[String], ?]`, instead of `Writer[String, ?]`. I guess that my case is too specific, and I have to implement it myself as @Edwing proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could elegantly be solved by adding an extra trait `ParseContext[T]`, which, apart from the original context, such as line number and 'original' text, is a Functor (`.map(f: T => T)`) and a Monad (`.flatMap(f: T => ParseContext[T])`). You could optionally make two instances of `ParseContext`, named `Success` and `Failure`, to indicate a possible failure during parsing.

Basically, you extend the `Try` trait with some extra context information.

Comment: is this Try extension already implemented in scalaz or somewhere else?
would scalaZ State be this extenstion, or it is totally different? http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html

Comment: I don't think the scalaz `State` really fits this problem. The solution is easy to implement, so it's always better to try implementing it first and then seeing which algabraic datatypes it matches.

Comment: I would prefer avoiding reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Then point us all to the wheel you're preferring not to reinvent.

Comment: As I said in my last comment to the question: ScalaZ `Writer` is what I once looked at and I thought it could be useful here, but I couldn't remember the name. However, I see that it results in `Writer[List[String], ?]`, instead of `Writer[String, ?`]. I guess that my case is too specific, and I have to implement it myself as @Edwing proposed. Though it does not seem easy; I'll take a look at this later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, collapsing your multiple `map`s into one would help?

```
 val result: List[(String, Try[Int])] = list
   .map { line =>
      line -> parseXML(line)
        .map(_ \ "@id")
        .text
        .flatMap(id => Try(id.toInt)
   }
```

Comment: my trivial example can indeed be collapsed into one map operation; but that's not why i am asking for.

Comment: What _are_ you asking for then?

Comment: How to make several map operations, while carrying the original string in an implicit way (instead of an explicit way). look at the answer of Edwin.

Comment: I thought you wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel ;)

Comment: I do; what makes you think the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicate strings in the list, you could make it a map, and then `mapValues` over it:

```
(l zip l toMap)
   .mapValues(parseXML)
   .mapValues(tryEntry => tryEntry.map(entry => (entry \ "@id").text))
   .mapValues(tryId => tryId.flatMap(id => Try(id.toInt)))
   .toList
```

Comment: you can always dedup: `(l zipWithIndex) zip l toMap`